# How to use nagios to monitor a printer

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have network based printers, and I was wondering, as all network printers with SNMP able to give up information such as if they need ink, or toners or just their general status.

I'm not the greatest fan of walking up and down flights of stairs checking printers, because users can't be bothered to mention that a printer isn't working. (Unless they have a deadline, in which case, they use the broken printer, and somehow remember exactly how to log incident tickets!)

Any hints and tips appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `check_snmp` plugin that comes with the standard nagios plugins.

Answer (score 3):

As Khaled said, you can use check_snmp to monitor the printers - you'll need to check the docs for your printers to see what OIDs to check for the things you want to monitor.  I expect that most of the things you are looking for will be snmp trap alerts rather than exposed through passive checks (checks initiated from Nagios) - I always struggled to get traps working with Nagios.

Alternatively, a lot of printers that support snmp also support email alerts for the same events.  That may do all you need without requiring Nagios.

Also note that if you want to monitor other printer counters, you may actually want to monitor the print queue on your server if you are using windows print queues.

Comment: So, I guess the next step really, would be to get the OIDs for my printer - and check the correct ones, with the check_snmp plugin. Also, monitoring the print queue on my server is an idea.

Comment: It is possible that the OIDs are fairly generic.  You could do an snmp_walk on the printer to see everything that is generated, but if you don't have the MIBs for the printer installed, the output may not mean anything to you.  Note again - this may only return the values for an snmp_query.  Some of the things you require might only be available via traps.  The MIBs and documentation for your printers (let's hope you don't have too many different ones) will give you the best overview.